# Dropdown List in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, drop-down-menu

The database is like this. Owner has many cats.

**Owner** ownerID ownerName

**Cat** catID catType ownerID

I am trying to add the new cat and on the field of ownerID, I want to show the droplist of all the ownerName. How can I do that?

Comment: do you have model of owner and cat ?

Comment: actually i am not working on these database. i am just trying to put the simple picture of the database.

Comment: you have to create a model for owner

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you already have owner model, for dropdown list of owner

**In Conrtoller**

```
$Owner = $this->Owner->find('list', array('fields' => array('Owner.ownerID', 'Owner.ownerName')));

$this->set('owners', $owner);
```

**In View**

```
<?php echo $form->input('owner', array(
        'label' => false,
        'id' => 'owner_id',
        'options' => $owners
    )); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write in your contoller:

```
$all_security_question = $this->Security_question->find('list',array('fields'=>array('id','question')));
$this->set("all_security_question",$all_security_question);


   Write in your Model:<?php echo $this->Form->input('security_question_id', array(
                                                'label' => false,
                                                'id' => 'id',
                                                'options' =>$all_security_question
                                            )); ?>
```